# Cannot delete a printer queue on OpenVMS

Tags: openvms, vms

Im trying to delete a printer queue but I always receive the message:
$> delete/que myprinter
%DELETE-E-NOTDELETED, error deleting MYPRINTER
-JBC-E-REFERENCED, existing references prevent deletion
$> sh que/all/full myprinter
Server queue MYPRINTER, stopped, on MYSERVER::, mounted form A4_LINEP_LS (stock=DEFAULT)
  /BASE_PRIORITY=4 /DEFAULT=(FEED,FORM=DEFAULT) /OWNER=[SYSTEM] /PROCESSOR=TCPIP$LPD_SMB /PROTECTION=(S:M,O:D,G:R,W:S) /RETAIN

I try the "user action" suggested in this cases - delete all entryes and references to the queue and apparently there is no more references since the $ show que/full/all command shows nothing.
Anyway, ther must have a hiden reference, but where? 
Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

From the OpenVMS System Manager's Manual: *the queue you are attempting to delete might be named as a target for a generic queue...*. To check for such a target queue do a `$ pipe show queue/generic/full |search sys$pipe generic`. If your queue shows you want to remove it from the generic queue.